# Unexpected unknown at-rule "@use" in stylelint

Tags: angular, sass, stylelint

I run stylelint in my angular project and I got error:

```
Unexpected unknown at-rule "@use"
```

My stylelint version is `"^13.12.0"`.

I don't want to disable this rule. I want stylelint to know about "@use" in scss files.

I also tested in stylelint demo website and I got the same error.

```
@use 'sass:list';

a {color: #FFF; }
```

[stylelint.io/demo](https://stylelint.io/demo#N4Igxg9gJgpiBcIACBXAzjABAcjQQzTXgBsBLNAF2wG4AdAOwb02EmIgCd5MBiAMQHVMAXwYgANCDQBPehTwAPBOEITwEegDNSAc2XAGmTLRAcUxGGhPcD9I0ZN4KAWjMXn9CM5T0A1p4B3RgRMCjMYcUN7EwAjdjBfDy8YAFsABwppa1DwyLto9XYOJOdSegA3PDIoZwALGAVssJQIqId1FJSYORLUjKyQ5tb89tgwYjwOJ1INZziIBJKoFDSyMCcYZzB0CggU5zSOCDSYDgpSSybctuMQMYmp89n5xc9nZdXSdYpNw+PT86XEIAbRuRiGeXs9lsUKhJl0ng4MGyoJGsPakHoGG253Kmw+aw2aGcAVIFFq71Imk0p26LkqxBaVhAYPsAF1WaI0WzIQV7pNps94ok3mhapxyXh6DU-icztJnBA8RwOKRYMzuBCbiZNBoXJo8ClSMQFW8CV8Nh5DUDNdc0Tq9c4DUaTSUjYQyjpnDpuqcvk7DcaFb4YNIApwoFcWrz2pofGAnvQtlUwCUygy1VHhnCQHH6AmZkn1sRU28fGg0ngwDAav9HpwszHbnmC7MyPQYJNvVMoBcem9PFj5NLJjVe0jW8FbdHtSAQ9JNFMuu8YOMBYm0+kJVKKI3Z11e3gnZ2KCgkVbl2W-IEpzkZ-aQPRrTUdKqapNO8S3umqpnBnaczNSxq2lT1nArVcqS+MkBmnbMCjNFZCR+ZwnFKLczlccwbTveD2kQz5vk2DALATTgNVwpsTDePpMnAiAz2rPcHxohQwiPDAjTYDQKK1FivB-ap3gYuJiImMUtj2Lo5F4gCEIEipfxlCA0DJQtUJcUgMJcNxkX-e9AIElUYB0cwuwCWoyUsSsmP0vDbllAFTS8Hx-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-bgP9YrquToHjFhdy+oFGTEmK-JlnMu44pF+17odHJA2xQlWfbkgNGelohUdb1+H6v2yv05nhuKoBq6FBu3cEahwHSGBlKwZrDGX8Bpf3hDoREU0GqNRMJQaQFh2wuFPikKUUAOpAM5DcYBOZEF0hJJZH448yiqVgF3OWx8TDbEoC1Ry8pNYbQlhPG+mBIHLQfq7WEF0HogGujAW6n9GpIzLlsZq+xqGZGPpdXMP8QYdkoAAyGjVMFVVAeAu6-DbgO1RslcRnDCFqmIlzTYOthSAIUeg7kmV+SPHUjEKUXpx4OwNh2Y2T8+SrgeIKJMNirbjxTpPGW98XZkLuG49c1izaC24qLcapdO5T1Yc4Gudcc4WJCVYoUTdwKpCFiLcCNkO7S3UfEuOfc9IpLXGkzx4SsmRNyT7XxjDqJG3XrOSxHifoZOKYY+hSCl6tMTBRAAjGU9xG53bsWNGBCJ89bzBzYaMVJbSal23oQ4uJ3dEmkAjv3Fx8zymLOmbUjWqz-HT2JJ0rZpSWkLI3DUnx18g6G2ccM0JswL4XIYRAu+pztEcJzNw3ht8v4CJRn0ws2icxA2kf-CGmMYbtDhp8oF6jBHYLkOC2GWI9E9xKe0hIJiqpY1hDjaGs4Ww3KkkeZZ-tjmFPWWHTZ9dMpkvUogjieTUJlxIRzc5jLSXxnJZ0NldT7mOKaeXJl-L1I9NoZfCWFEAAMEr8wbjpkTAgDy17ir5cq9SlYkRyHqBgL80T6G6OIWs6u9KLlBOZbMPVdJDWWEOZsM1DynGnGxV07ZSrJy4KsvYzlFrH6ZTKLAOQHjsgACZMoWBGuSZwAAvU4Xgrxkkiu0aVbzJqDMygeUgR4aRODPETA5AbYknNYUEvNBaTzFskjku5qcK7uq1Q+atx4i3nlVcvDV7lmltprPmjtp5zz2oNZYJ1BDMXmv8S2qtg6a2ds2FMEamw6xOFymWgpsz52HmHXWldPpFRyg3R9dl9SHnfJ2bcdtABHFoHBZUg1ZSXFZgaK10trgy5J+4F3OHvacJ9CCKXOo5eW2lGceU-oHXugDj6I7PpA42vxtw53XuoskYWfr8F5PTahrw7o44JWlIqTQ9FGK2xNdsuCmV6AoBSLrYoFg8C9itkmo4XK5mofo4xko4z2xenYypPDJhREKmJr2imracyrSzfQi9qjOGnISVa3l91fkFH+R-QFaidRSL-rImFQC4XVTASh5hEiNGoo-pjMx-VMrRV8hpMIpAYgoBQgnEMFAznstdaKp5g1soxWc6qNzKF11Oa3eXWdYqgmOdyk4FzYW10nsi+ekVzbYvoayqRJzp8YhlFPaBmlO7svxeKPlwraXhVNo-aQsrQWnPqhAlAHcqMCtPicwOWY7cRM5Zykx8gwHBWvupe+iDwbAu5dymQRDI3kMNMef2ryjXcqZvWrKmR2RFVTYGwcOKwVxLEgkwbTVcXVuxRgIFQ7BBiRjvJBOnzPs-OZYCw+cr+2rvxWyslHtp2+3Saihdz713WqpBwUsiA8hEwGyCigUS53pvFHymqle-izvZdmgg9V-2pNBIZC0Zw85wwcBqCd1eAP8dVEJ7N4bSDRv5OixN4kGzrXZYJ10ub9Ooucc9WzzKHOEN06FcnDLMW3s5kF7ThJigZUXIVVELkwgQDCCAA)

Stylelint doesn't support `@use`?

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: There's a [Stylelint plugin](https://github.com/stylelint-scss/stylelint-scss) specifically for SCSS, have you given that a try? I presume the lint error you're seeing is behaving as intended because `@use` isn't available in vanilla CSS.

Comment: yes it's solve the problem. thanks

Comment: FWIW, this did not fix the issue for me

Answer (score 0):

If you're linting SCSS with Stylelint, the ["Getting started" guide](https://stylelint.io/user-guide/get-started) within the [Stylelint documentation](https://stylelint.io/) now [recommends](https://stylelint.io/user-guide/get-started#linting-everything-else) extending the [`stylelint-config-standard-scss` shared config](https://www.npmjs.com/package/stylelint-config-standard-scss). It will configure Stylelint for SCSS.

You can install the config using:

```
npm install --save-dev stylelint-config-standard-scss
```

And then update your Stylelint configuration object to extend it:

```
{
  "extends": "stylelint-config-standard-scss"
}
```